# oracle export failed due to unable to close dump file

Tags: oracle, database-administration

The export is failing due to below error

ORA-31693: Table data object "x"."x_t" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-31643: unable to close dump file ""

Anyone has knowledge regarding this issue, please help out

Comment: There should be additional errors there; are they? If so, which ones?

Comment: No other errors present

Comment: What is command line to start expdp? What is parameter file for expdp?

Comment: parameter file--

Comment: dumpfile=xxxxxxxx
logfile=xxxxxxx
directory=xxxxxxx




filesize=31g
full=y
exclude=table:xxxxxx
exclude=table:xxxxxx



exclude=statistics
parallel=4
cluster=n
exclude=schema:xxxxxx

Comment: What is command line to start expdp?       Its a scheduler